# Undefined values in Javascript array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add 2 values to an array that I extract from a html page. However, the value for key [0] always returns **undefined** whereas I expect 4 in this case.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function ()
  {
    var arrayList = $("some class");
    var x = new Array(); 
    var j = 0;
    var k = 1;

    $.each(arrayList, function(i,e) {

      var MyIf = $(e).text(); 
      x[j] = new Array();

      if(k == 2) {
        x[j][0] = 4; // This always returns undefined, no matter which value I assign.
      }

      if(k == 3) {
        x[j][1] = parseInt(MyIf);
      }

      if(k % 3 == 0) {
        j++;
        k = 1;
      } else {
        k++;
      }

    });
    console.log(x); // the console returns for all [0] "undefined"
  });
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How many elements does `arrayList` have? If it has only 1, I would expect `x` to be empty since you only add to it when `k == 2` or `k == 3`. In other words, how many times does your `$.each` loop run?

Comment: arrayList has multiple values. Current output looks like this: [[undefined, 3], [undefined, 5], [undefined, 2]]

Comment: A fiddle will help...

Comment: Are you sure that k==2 sometimes?

Comment: what is this code trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you create a new array every time in your `each`.

```
x[j] = new Array();
```

so it's always undefined.

put it in here:

```
if(k % 3 == 0) {
        j++;
        k = 1;
        x[j] = new Array();
      }
```

and don't forget to call `x[j] = new Array();` before your first run.

Comment: so how does it explain that the Array still has values for x[j][1] ?

Comment: because you make a new array an then set the value `x[j][1] = somevalue;`

Comment: @KrisVandenBergh Because when `k == 3` it adds to the last created Array at index `1`. Then, `j` is increased so it will not touch that same Array anymore.

Comment: @Homungus If you do `x[j] = []` in the `k % 3 == 0` case, `x[j]` will be undefined in the `k == 2` and `k == 3` cases above it the very first run. Perhaps not pretty, but you can do on the first line of the  `.each` loop a `if(typeof x[j] === 'undefined') x[j] = [];` which fixes it (and remove it from the `k % 3 == 0` case entirely).

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers you are right, of course it should be initialized before first run. updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed important to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be done like this:

```
var arrayList = [1,2,3,4,5];
var x = new Array(); 
var j = 0;
var k = 1;
x[j] = new Array();
$.each(arrayList, function(i,e) {

  var MyIf = $(e).text(); 


  if(k == 2) {
    x[j][0] = 4; // This always returns undefined, no matter which value I assign.
  }

  if(k == 3) {
    x[j][1] = parseInt(MyIf);
  }

  if(k % 3 == 0) {
    j++;
    x[j] = new Array();
    k = 1;
  } else {
    k++;
  }

});
console.log(x);
```

In your code, when the k variable is equal 3, you overwrite the previous value doing this:

```
x[j] = new Array();

  if(k == 2) {
    x[j][0] = 4; // This always returns undefined, no matter which value I assign.
  }
```